# Spinner in Android (With phone codes and automatic country recognition)

Tags: android, xml, spinner, android-spinner

I would like to create a spinner in Android XML, which will have list of the phone codes (ex. USA - +1), and after choosing the phone code at the bottom I want a program to show the country name of the chosen phone code. It should work automatically, which means whenever I change the phone code, it will change the name of the Country.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything? It's important to show us some code of your effort so we can help you properly.

Comment: There are many guides on the internet about that. Check this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aApS2W-j8oM

Comment: have you tried any code the please share it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use 3rd party library for this.
https://github.com/hbb20/CountryCodePickerProject/blob/master/README.md?fbclid=IwAR1tz_D3PTEUyy2-zaGG0QTZWda_8ss9nbSml-z7zyI3gULLFsibIlRhujs
if you want to you own program you can try i can help if any difficult situation.